# TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function in Yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I am using textfield for search

```
        <?php echo CHtml::textField('companysearch', '', 
       array("onkeyup" => "$.fn.yiiGridView.update('company-table', {type: 'GET', 
       data: {companyName: this.value}});",
        "class" => "txt-srh", "placeholder" => "Search")); ?>
```

While doing this I am getting error **TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function**

hw can i escape from this

Comment: Try to include scripts for `gridView` directly on page via `Yii::app()->clientScript`. It's problem with scripts load most likely.

Comment: What script i ave to include for it

Answer (score 3):

check if you included jquery.js more than once in your page. I had the same error and the reason was that yii already added the jquery.js script so no needs to include it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are including jQuery more than once. Make sure first to **replace/deregister** the default Yii jQuery version (probably 1.x), then add yours in `Controller.php` inside `init()` function:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;
//Add custom jQuery version
$cs->scriptMap = array(
      'jquery.js' => $baseUrl.'/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    );
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```