# JavaScript error $.param.querystring is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, function, search, filter

I have an issue with price filter on PHP web page. I am not that good in JavaScript to find the problem by myself and even more, I came across this filter after the developer left.

Could anyone please check the problem with my search filer, located on:

https://ngod.com.ua/category/podarki-v-kartonnoy-upakovke with **code attached below this message**?

When I try to change the pricing it should go with filtering, but instead it gives

```
in **Google Console Uncaught TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function**
    at SearchFunc (podarki-v-kartonnoy-upakovke:3240)
    at podarki-v-kartonnoy-upakovke:3224
```

and nothing filtering.

The code of filter:

```
<?= CHtml::beginForm('', 'get', array('id'=>'searchform', 'class'=>'filters')); ?>

<?= CHtml::hiddenField('Product[firm]', $model->firm); ?>
<div class="side-filter-body m-b-1">
    <h5 class="content-title"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Подобрать подарок')?></h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span><?= Yii::t('app', 'Цена')?>: </span>
        <?= CHtml::numberField('Product[price_min]', $model->min_price, array('min'=>$model->min_price)); ?>                                
        <span> - </span>
        <?= CHtml::numberField('Product[price_max]', $model->max_price, array('max'=>$model->max_price)); ?>    
        <span>грн</span>
    </div>

    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSliderInput', array(
            'id'=>'price',
            'name'=>'',
            'event'=>'change',
            'options'=>array(
                'values'=>array($model->min_price, $model->max_price),// default selection
                'step'=>5,
                'min'=>$model->min_price, //minimum value for slider input
                'max'=>$model->max_price, // maximum value for slider input
                'animate'=>true,
                'slide'=>'js:function(event,ui){
                                $("#Product_price_min").val(ui.values[0]);
                                $("#Product_price_max").val(ui.values[1]);
                                setTimeout(function () {SearchFunc()}, 500);
                            }',
            )
        ));
    ?>  

    <hr class="m-t-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span><?= Yii::t('app', 'Вес')?>: </span>
        <?= CHtml::numberField('Product[weight_min]', $model->min_weight, array('min'=>$model->min_weight)); ?>                             
        <span> - </span>
        <?= CHtml::numberField('Product[weight_max]', $model->max_weight, array('max'=>$model->max_weight)); ?> 
        <span>грам</span>
    </div>

    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSliderInput', array(
            'id'=>'weight',
            'name'=>'',
            'event'=>'change',
            'options'=>array(
                'values'=>array($model->min_weight, $model->max_weight),// default selection
                'step'=>5,
                'min'=>$model->min_weight, //minimum value for slider input
                'max'=>$model->max_weight, // maximum value for slider input
                'animate'=>true,
                'slide'=>'js:function(event,ui){
                                $("#Product_weight_min").val(ui.values[0]);
                                $("#Product_weight_max").val(ui.values[1]);
                                setTimeout(function () {SearchFunc()}, 500);
                            }',
            )
        ));
    ?>
</div>
<?= CHtml::endForm(); ?>

<?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search',
    "$('#searchform').change(function(event) {
        SearchFunc();
        return false;
    });
    function SearchFunc()   {
        var data = $('#searchform').serialize();
        var url = document.URL;
        var params = $.param(data);
        url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('?'));
        window.History.pushState(null, document.title,$.param.querystring(url[0], data));
    }
");
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311578/typeerror-param-querystring-is-not-a-function-in-yii)

Comment: Well the error has nothing to do with PHP but the included Javascript

Comment: @empiric Would u pls be more specific?

Comment: @tripleee yes, I have seen this topic prior to opening this message. But it didnt help.

Comment: More specifically the error message is not about anything in your PHP code. It is complaining about a JavaScript error.

Comment: @tripleee most likely, because I have checked a lot of pages with similar issues. Can u please tell me if the problem with SearchFunc in the bottom of the code, or the problem is somewhere outside of this code filter?

Comment: Please take care to not roll back useful edits. Stack Overflow generally removes "hello", "thanks" etc from posts to keep the signal to noise ratio pleasant.